# Fetching JSON Data and passing to Directive Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, amcharts

Lets assume I'm receiving JSON Data via AJAX in a Service like this:

```
.factory('JSONObject', function() {

  //Connect to a resource, gather some JSON Data
  ...
  return {
    all: function() {
      return jsonObject;
    }
  }
});
```

The Service returns a JSON Array with time-value Fields. What I want to do is to fill a Chart with this Information whenever my Controller is called. I am currently using **AMCharts** in my custom directive and render this Chart into a *div* in my View called "chartdiv". AMCharts need its Data to be put in the **$chartdata** Variable to do its magic.

```
    .directive('randomDirective',
   function () {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           replace:true,

           template: '<div id="chartdiv" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>',
           link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                var initChart = function() {

                  // Get Chartdata Measurements
              $chartdata = ????

                  var config = scope.config || {};
                   chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",
                {
                    "type": "serial",
                    "categoryField": "date",
                    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM",
                    "graphs": [
                        {
                            "id": "AmGraph-2",
                            "lineColor": "#FFFFFF",
                            "lineThickness": 2,
                            "title": "graph 1",
                            "valueField": "vm"
                        }
                    ],
                    "dataProvider": $chartdata
                }
            );
                };
                initChart();

         }
       }
```

My Controller is currently pretty empty as well

```
.controller('DetailsCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.title = '2012';
})
```

How do I fill the **$chartdata** Variable in my Directive with JSON Objects from my Factory, whenever my Controller is called/activated?

Answer (score 0):

Usually need to set a watcher on a scope variable in the directive and wait for the data to come into the controller, something like this. I know nothing about AMCharts, but this is the way I do it with D3, usually. . .

```
.directive('randomDirective', function() { 
  return {
     scope: 'myData', 
     replace: true, 
     link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

       //the true parameter at the end makes it a deep watch.
       $scope.$watch('myData', function(newVal, oldVal) {
         if (newVal) {
           $scope.data = newVal
           drawChart($scope.data)
         } 
       }, true)

       function drawChart() {
         //All that stuff to draw the chart
       }

     }
  }

}
```